# C#: Get IP Address from Domain Name?

Tags: c#, ip-address

How can I get an IP address, given a domain name?
For example: `www.test.com`

Comment: What about getting domain name from IP?

Comment: @Moshe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716748/c-reverse-ip-domain-check

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `System.Net.Dns` class:

```csharp
Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.test.com");
```

Comment: Also note it is PLURAL - and not all of them may work at a given time.

Comment: True, but i think it rare case that this method returns more then one address, especially in case of internet domains.

Comment: @Brian - six IPs! WOW! so you need to store them all and pick next if one doesn't work.

Comment: @RollRoll because not all addresses may be working, which is the point of multiple A Records.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the [GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) method:

```
var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.test.com")[0];
```

Comment: no good. what if result set is 0? or more probably more than 1?

Comment: @Moshe: It should if you have access to the `System.Net.Dns` class.

Comment: @Andrey: If more than one, it would just ignore the rest. If 0, I guess it would crash :p

Comment: @Moshe, in VB.NET : `Dim address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.test.com")(0)`

Comment: @Andrey, @Svish - Silly me, but of course. @Darin Dimitrov - Thanks.

Comment: Worked great for me! All I needed was the first IP!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same results by using:

```
Dns.GetHostAddresses("yahoo.com");
```

or

```
await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync("yahoo.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer could be more the same above answers, but here i get the current web app hosted URL / domain name using code and obtained the IP address and from that. I used the code in my **C# MVC Web app**  and its working fine.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)HttpContext).Request.Url.ToString());
var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(myUri.Host).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```