# How to Ping for IPv4 only?

Tags: c#, .net, ping, ipv4, traceroute

I know my router's IPv4 address. But when I Ping using TTL = 1 I don't get that IP. Rather, I get its IPv6 address. (I know of `address.MapToIPv4()` but that's only for IPv4s that were changed into IPv6s.)

So how do I ping for IPv4 only (like [tracert's /4 switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tracert))?

```
var reply = new Ping().Send("example.com", 10000, new byte[] { 1 }, new PingOptions(1, true));
```

Comment: Can you add code which you tried ?  Also why can't you fire Ping command from the c# code ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I do. See update.

Comment: @ispiro at least I am now curious to know the answer for your question with a supportive +

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks. :)

Comment: Possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462170/c-get-ip-address-from-domain-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source code ([Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/NetworkInformation/ping.cs,289), [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/2696d751a7b50bdc3e03bf5089f67aa0bd081b24/src/System.Net.Ping/src/System/Net/NetworkInformation/Ping.cs#L388)), if the parameter passed to [`Send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send) is a name then [`Dns.GetHostAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses) is used to resolve it and the first address returned is what's used.  Thus, if that first address is an IPv6 address then that address is what will be pinged and there's no way to change that behavior.

Instead, you could call [`Dns.GetHostAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses) yourself, filter the results to include or prefer IPv4 addresses, and pass *that* to [`Ping.Send()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.send):

```
IPAddress addressToPing = Dns.GetHostAddresses("example.com")
    .First(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

using (Ping ping = new Ping())
{
    PingReply reply = ping.Send(addressToPing, 10000, new byte[] { 1 }, new PingOptions(1, true));

    // Do something with reply...
}
```