# Finding valid URLs

Tags: c#

I have a C# script that finds URLs and checks each one to see if it is valid. To be valid, it must have an IP address which means it will return info if queried in a nslookup. Not all valid URLs have a webpage, but they will have an IP address. That being the case, test for a website will not work. I searched for solutions but did not find a simple one.

My current method does a system call to nslookup and places it into a List. Then I loop through the list and check for "Non-existent domain". This works but I prefer not to use system calls if a C# alternative is available.

I can use HtmlAgilityPack and do a call to "https://www.whois.com/whois/" but some foreign URLs are not listed there and it seems like a lot of overhead for this kind of search.

I've tried the following System.Net method but no matter what URL I use, it fails.

```
string validURL = "a good URL";
try {
  Uri myUri = new Uri(validURL);
  var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(myUri.Host)[0];
  Console.WriteLine("Found it");
} catch {
  Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}
```

What is a good low cost method to determine if a URL is valid or fails?

Comment: You can ping by either IP or Host name.

Comment: I'm still confused by the criteria here. You're saying that a "valid" URL is 1) parsable by the `Uri` class, and 2) the host portion of that URI must be an IP address? Can you give an example of good and bad inputs? If you're having a problem just determining an IP from a domain name, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462170/c-get-ip-address-from-domain-name) seems like what you're asking, and I don't understand why `Dns.GetHostAddresses` isn't preferable to you.

Comment: With `validURL = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"` your code prints "Found it".

Comment: Here is an example: boardriders-mkt-stage5-res.adobe-campaign.com
You can ping it, do nslookup and find it in ARIN, but it does not resolve as a webpage. For the code I listed, I think it has to start with http/s to work. For example, www.cnn.com fails but https:// www.cnn.com works. Ping might be an option but not all URLs ping for a variety of reasons even though the resolve in NSLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Pretty simple.

```
string validURL = "any url or ip adddress";
try { 
  IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(validURL);
} 
catch {
  Console.WriteLine("Failed");
}
```

If I have a need for the Host name and IP addresses it's done with just a few extra lines of code in the try section.