# How to get domain name?

Tags: ip

How to get domain name by ip?

I got IP address and port also (not sure if it's important), and I need domain name.
I know where I can locate IP, but how can I check for domain name?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if and only if a [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) has been configured by the entity controlling the IP.

> In computer networking, reverse DNS lookup or reverse DNS resolution (rDNS) is the determination of a domain name that is associated with a given IP address using the Domain Name System (DNS) of the Internet.
>
> Computer networks use the Domain Name System to determine the IP address associated with a domain name. This process is also known as forward DNS resolution. Reverse DNS lookup is the inverse process, the resolution of an IP address to its designated domain name.
>
> The reverse DNS database of the Internet is rooted in the Address and Routing Parameter Area (arpa) top-level domain of the Internet. IPv4 uses the in-addr.arpa domain and the ip6.arpa domain is delegated for IPv6. The process of reverse resolving an IP address uses the pointer DNS record type (PTR record).

Note that not every IP needs to be associated with an DNS address, and in fact many are not.

> So is there way to get domain name of this : 83.125.22.197:21

Yes, you can use an online reverse DNS lookup tool like

http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

This IP looks up to

> f10-www.runhosting.com

If you need to do that in C#, see

[Reverse IP Domain Check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716748/reverse-ip-domain-check)

Comment: 83.125.22.197:21  Can u get domain name of this ?? @Eric J.

Comment: There are different methods to lookup a DNS record, depending on your programming language and platform.  What are you using?  Note that `:21` is not part of your IP address.  That is a port number.  Also you will have to configure a PTR record if you are responsible for the domain and IP address.  The details of doing that depend on how your DNS is managed.

Comment: Well,I would know how to do it,if there was some website with this command.Anyway,using c#. @Eric J.

Comment: So is there way to get domain name of this : 83.125.22.197:21
I really really need this,please help! @Eric J.