# host name who using my API controller in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

IN MVC 5 PROJECT
suppose I have API like

```
abc.com/authonication?userName=asdklfsdf&token=ASDF45FEWF312DFSFWE465SDF465
```

And some another web app (example.com) use this API

In my controller, I want to get the host name (example.com) of domain who using this API to validate

Comment: That's not how networks work. The request is issued from an IP address. You could do a reverse lookup to see which names are registered to that IP address, but that's not foolproof. See also [Reverse IP Domain Check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716748/reverse-ip-domain-check).

Comment: Is `example.com` calling your website from the client (the web browser) or the server (e.g. IIS)?

Comment: example.com calling from browser

Answer (score 2):

You can get some useful information from the HttpContext.Request field.

```
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
HttpContext.Request.UserHostName
```

This information is not necessarily available, but in a lot of cases, it's there.  Just don't depend on it.

Comment: from here HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress i am gettting "ip address" and HttpContext.Request.UserHostName i am getting machine name

Comment: As I said, it depends on many things, including the browser actually sending that information.  Some browsers won't include it.  For some requests, you WILL get the machine name, especially if you are trying it locally.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this at your API Action method itself.

```
[HttpGet]
public object Add(string data = "")
{
    try
    {
        string result = "0";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            var host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
            var ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }

        return new { response = result };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

[i found this here.](https://forums.asp.net/t/2014163.aspx?Asp%20NET%20MVC%20REST%20API%20How%20to%20get%20Client%20Domain%20Name)